# Why does exit status of system() call in Ruby change with redirection?

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault, exit-code

I have slimmed down an issue I am facing to an MWE. Can anybody confirm if it is a bug or I am missing something rudimentary?

**Platform**:

- Ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
- GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- Ubuntu 14.04.2 x86_64

**Step 1**: Create a Ruby script as follows named `demo.rb`

```
ret = system("./segfault")
print "Return value: ", ret, "\n"
print "Exit status: ", ($?.exitstatus) ? $?.exitstatus : "nil", "\n"
print "Status code: ", $?.to_i, "\n"
puts "-----------------------------------"
ret = system("./segfault 2>&1")
print "Return value: ", ret, "\n"
print "Exit status: ", ($?.exitstatus) ? $?.exitstatus : "nil", "\n"
print "Status code: ", $?.to_i, "\n"
```

**Step 2**: Create a C program as follows named `segfault.c`

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    memset((char *)0x0, 1, 100);
    return 1;
}
```

**Step 3**: Compile the C program.

```
gcc segfault.c -o segfault
```

**Step 4**: Run the Ruby script.

```
$ ruby segfault.rb 
Return value: false
Exit status: nil
Status code: 139
-----------------------------------
sh: line 1:  8181 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./segfault 2>&1
Return value: false
Exit status: 139
Status code: 35584
```

I can't understand why the exit status and status code changes with `stderr` being redirect to `stdout`. Does anyone have a reasonable explanation of this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The command you give to system can take multiple forms. If it is just the path to the command or if it is a path and an array of arguments then ruby forks and execs that command directly.

If it is anything more complicated then it executes what it considers the standard shell and passes the command to the shell.

The reason this is relevant is in the docs for `exitstatus` which say:

> Returns the least significant eight bits of the return code of stat. Only available if `exited?` is true.

And the docs for `exited?` say

> Returns true if stat exited normally (for example using an exit() call or finishing the program).

Your c binary does not exit normally, so in your first case `exited?` is false and exitstatus retuns nil In the second case while your binary is still failing in the same way, the actual process executed by ruby was a instance of your shell, which did exit normally.

I get different results as far as $?.to_i is concerned. The low 8 bits contain information such as whether a signal was raised and the high 8 bits contain the exit status.

I get 11 and 35584 (139<<8) in your 2 cases, but your version of ruby seems to be behaving like bash and adding 128 to the signal value (segfault is signal 11).

Either way the cause of the difference is whether the command is executed via a shell: the shell sees the failed process and turns its signal value into a exit status (stored in the high 8 bits) whereas when executed directly there is no exit status and error information is in the low 8 bits.

As an aside, you can redirect output using options passed to system eg

```
system("mycommand", err: :out)
```

Redirects stderr to stdout as you were doing

Comment: Even I have seen `$?.to_i == 11` in other cases. I am not being able to reproduce the same her though. It just appears in another larger program, seemingly randomly. Therefore, I can't quite rely on `$?`. Which combination of Bash/Ruby are you using?

Comment: If I use `system("./segfault", err: : out)`, the following doesn't appear: `sh: line 1:  8181 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./segfault 2>&1`

Comment: Ruby 2.3.0, bash 3.2.57. Personally I would always avoid the use of the shell invoking form of system

Comment: That's because that form also avoids spawning a shell

Comment: Security is not a concern in my case. It's a tool prototype I am building. Sanitizing doesn't apply as strictly as in commercial ones.

Comment: It's not just about security - involving a shell often complicates things (eg argument parsing, shell globbing etc) and apparently exit codes.